# How to keep router link active state on if the parent route is activate

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a menu which has 4 sections

- Home
- Categories
- HowItWorsk
- About

If user select Categories my URL change to the `/categories/section1`.
In my section1 component I have 2 button which points to a `categories/section2`, `categories/section3`.

Problem is routerLinkActive only works for `/categories/section1`, what I want is `routerLinkActivate` to be true if the URL has `/categories/*`.

I went through a lot of questions like that but none of them fix my issue. I have a stack blitz example found when I am trying to find a solution.
[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7qivp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Could you share the template code

Comment: Share your routes settings with us

Comment: @C_Ogoo  this exact same thing instead of the category this example use doctors https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7qivp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Akxe this exact same thing instead of the categories this example use doctors https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7qivp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own `routerLinkActive` and then use `[class.active]` to toggle the active class.

You basically get the current url from the `Router` and check if it includes your path e.g. if you want `/categories/*` use `this.router.url.includes('/categories/')`.

> Edit

According to your comment you can make this code a bit more dynamic

component

```js
constructor(
   private router: Router,
) {}

public isActive(base: string): boolean {
   return this.router.url.includes(`/${base}`);
}
```

template

```html
<a [class.active]="isActive('Categories')"> Im orange when you are on the route "Categories" </a>
<a [class.active]="isActive('HowItWorks')"> Im orange when you are on the route "HowItWorks" </a>
```

css

```css
.active {
   color: orange
}
```

Now you only have to create a css class `active`

Comment: if I add the same routing structure used in categories to the  how it works does this method works for that as well

Comment: @NicoleZ I did adjust the answer to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
 [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }"
```

Comment: not working.because of when user initial click on the categories button my router link points to the `/categories/section1`in that section1 component I have a list of categories if users click on one of those categories in the list url changes to this `categories/create` when that happen routerlinkActive not working.

Comment: As you said to your next answer, my suggestion is the correct one.

Comment: for some reason, your solution didn't work for me.your solution work if my intail route points to the `routerLink=" categories"` , In my category component I have `<router-outlet>` otherwise it will display an empty screen,so  in that case, I need to specifically point my router link to this `routerLink="categories/section1"`

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix this. I change my `routerLink="categories/section1"` to `routerLink="categories"` and new records with empty path the in routes configuration.newly added path look like this `{path: '',component: Section01Component},` 
now my template look like this `<a  routerLink="categories" routerLinkActive="active"></a>`.now you can navigate among the child routes without routerLinkActive deactive.

```
              {
                    path: 'categories',
                    component: CategoriesHomeComponent,
                    children: [
                    {
                            path: '',
                            component: Section01Component,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'section1',
                        component: Section01Component,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'section2',
                        component: Section02Component,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'section3',
                        component: Section03Component,
                    },

                    ]

                },
```

Comment: This is not a good option. Use @Michalis answer, or at least put the routes in children, docs here https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component

Comment: @Akxe Michalis's answer not worked for me.can you tell why this is not a good option

Comment: This way the first child is always selected, but if it had children it would only be selected if one of its children matches.